# In Ruby on Rails, what is the simplest method to create a dynamic input (order) page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, web-applications, dynamicform

I am new to web development (I do have several years of experience in server side).
I need to create a page where one enters order information.
For example: Item Name, Quantity, Price
Then one can click an "Add" button and another line of input will appear and the user can fill that.
In the end the user clicks "Submit" and the order is processed.

Now I know how to make a winforms application that does that, but I am new to rails, and in general to web development, could someone please point me to the right technology/package?

Perhaps someone has a link to a relevant tutorial? (I have done most of the rails tutorial but did not see anything like that there)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want **[dynamic nested model forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)**.

Here is a **[gem that makes it work out of the box](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form)**

Note: you will need to use jquery or prototype javascript frameworks.

One of the most common gotchas:

Make sure the parent model has **attr_accessible :children_attributes**.

Example: **School has_many :students**, you would need **attr_accessible :students_attributes** in your **School** model

You can read up on this and more at RailsAPI page for **[accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)**

Comment: Seems cool, it is what I was looking for and will give me an idea on what technologies to use to develop similar things. Tnx!

Answer (score 2):

You need to have an `Order` model and `OrderItem` model (name, quantity, price) for individual order items. `Order` model has many to one relationship with `OrderItem`. `Order` accepts nested attributes for order items. Create a form for `Order` together with fields for `OrderItem` attributes. For the `Add button` functionality use [Cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon). All you need to do now is to save it in `create` action.

[Cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon)'s homepage contains several examples that you can adapt to your problem - `project/tasks` is the same as `order/order_items` relationship. Also take a look at [#196 Nested Model Form Part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) that discuss similar topic.

If not solve your problem, this should hopefully give you something to Google for.

Answer (score 1):

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1
http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

These 2 screen casts probably almost identical to what you are trying to accomplish, just different context. They are old, but the basics still apply. I would probably approach the javascript portions differently these days.

Answer (score -1):

If you are new to rails and want to get quickly into it, then check this guide:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

The point 5 (Generate a Scaffold) fits your needs.

After creating a new rails application you could run:

```
rails generate scaffold Order name:string quantity:string price:integer
```

This generates you Controller, Model and Views related to the ordering process.

Run

```
rake db:setup
rake db:migrate
```

to prepare the database

Now everything should be fine and you got a page where the user can enter the order information and save it (witch should fit your start needs). Start the Server with

```
rails s
```

and check it out.